# MVC5 GetImageFromRequest is null when the model is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing a asp net MVC5 web application. I have a ViewModel with the next property:

```
public class ExampleViewModel //: IValidatableObject
{
   ...
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string Foto { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I upload the image in the view like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Ingresos", FormMethod.Post, new { @encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  ...

 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen" class="hidden" accept="image/*" />
          @if (Model != null && Model.Foto != null)
          {
              <img src="@Model.Foto" class="thumb" id="preview" />
          }
          else
          {
              <img class="thumb" id="preview" hidden />
           }
           <label class="btn btn-default" for="imagen">Examinar...</label>
           <label id="mensajeErrorImagen"></label>
           <br />
           @if (Model != null && Model.Foto != null)
           {
               <a id="botonEliminar" onclick="eliminarImagen()" style="cursor: pointer;">[Eliminar]</a>
           }
           else
           {
               <a id="botonEliminar" onclick="eliminarImagen()" style="cursor: pointer;"></a>
           }
    </div>
 </div>

 ...
}
```

And in the controller I get the image of this way

```
public ActionResult Create( ExampleViewModel ivm ){
   WebImage imagenW = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
   if (imagenW != null)
   {
      ivm.Foto = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imagenW.GetBytes());
   }
   if (Model.IsValid){
     //do something...
   }
   return (View(ivm))
}
```

This works well for me when the model is valid. When the model is not valid the  image is loaded in the view but in the controller `imagenW` is null. 
What is going on?

**EDIT**

The scenary where the error occurs is as follows:

1. I completed the form with the image and some errors in fields and I submit.
2. The view is shown with the error menssage and the preview of the image uploaded.
3. I submited the form again without changes .
4. The view is shown again with the same error message but this time the preview of the image is empty.

`imagenW` is null the second consecutive time a validation error occurs in the form.

Answer (score 1):

because this error appear only in the second time of post 
so you have to save it in some place like hidden field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.Foto);
```

you have to check if the `Model.Foto == null` then read from `imagenW` else
read from `Model.Foto`

the code will be

```
public ActionResult Create( ExampleViewModel ivm ){
          if(ivm.Foto ==null){
               WebImage imagenW = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
               if (imagenW != null)
               {
                   ivm.Foto = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imagenW.GetBytes());
               }
           }
           if (Model.IsValid){
             //do something...
           }
           return (View(ivm))
        }
```